# MPAndroidChart not drawing pie chart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using [mpAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library to draw pie-chart on android app. Library works when entries are more than two but it does not draw on single entries. Please advice where I am going wrong. I followed official [example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/PieChartActivity.java) given in the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error in my code and finally removed it! [Here](https://github.com/NayanSrivastav/Bounty-Android-Personal-Finance/blob/master/src/adapter/TransactionReportAdapter.java) Values were mistakenly not getting added in some cases, I have found and resolved the bug and code is now working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it didn't show up unless I changed the height of chart to "match_parent".

Since it was in the LinearLayout(LL), I added another LL in the original LL and set the value of LL as 300pd or 500pd.

Now I see the chart.